# hide input field when checkbox is checked and in localStorage jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to hide input boxes using `checkboxes`, Saving the `checkbox` name in the `localStorage` and `.hide()` on the `input` works, however when I refresh the page it doesn't persist the `input` field to be hidden, nor the `checkbox` to be `uncheck`.

Can someone point out what I'm missing, I know the check `if()` is still incomplete, I tried doing a `for()` inside the `if` to get the `localStorage` values and doing `('#'+forVal).hide()` or `('#' + forVal).prop('checked', false)` but that didn't work at all.

The `inputs` are dynamic

```
searchParams = getObjects(apiPaths[i].get.parameters);
for (var x = 0; x < searchParams.length; x++) {
    var container = $('#checkBox');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;
    var inputName = searchParams[x].name;
    $('<textarea />', { id: inputName, name: inputName, placeholder: inputName, rows: "2", class: "search-area-txt col-sm-12" }).appendTo(searchbox);
    var chkBoxElement = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: inputName, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
    chkBoxElement.click(function () {
          checkBoxSetting(this.id);
    });
    chkBoxElement.prop('checked', true); // initially all inputs are checked

    $('<label />', { 'for': 'x' + id, text: inputName, id: inputName, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
}
```

Checks the `localStorage` for checkboxes

```
var inputNames = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('chked') !== null) {
    inputNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chked'));
}
```

Saving it to the `localStorage`

```
function checkBoxSetting(id) {
    var indexOfItem = inputNames.indexOf(id)
    if (indexOfItem >= 0) {
        inputNames.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
    } else {
        inputNames.push(id);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('chked', JSON.stringify(inputNames));
    $("#" + inputNames).hide();
}
```

Example html with the saving to `localStorage`

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sd3DR42Ge61gDjap95ru?p=preview)**

Html text fields

```
<textarea id="id" name="id" placeholder="id" rows="2" class="search-area-txt col-sm-12"></textarea>
<textarea id="sku" name="sku" placeholder="sku" rows="2" class="search-area-txt col-sm-12"></textarea>
<textarea id="code" name="code" placeholder="code" rows="2" class="search-area-txt col-sm-12"></textarea>
```

Checkbox

```
<div id="checkBox">
 <input type="checkbox" id="id" name="id">
 <label for="id" id="id" name="id">id</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="sku" name="sku">
 <label for="sku" id="sku" name="sku">sku</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="code" name="code"><label for="code" id="code" name="code">code</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you stand a test page up somewhere (e.g. codepen) so we can see it in action?

Comment: Where do you put pack the values from localstorage to the HTML-dom?

Comment: Give us some HTML as well

Comment: @danwellman I've created an `input` with `checkbox` including the `functions()` I have above. So it shows that its saving and hiding the input. and there's no error at all in my console

Answer (score 1):

This is a beginning of a solution. This handles the local storage and checks the checkbox if it has been checked when you reload the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inputNames = []

  if (localStorage.getItem('chked') !== null) {
    inputNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chked'));
    $("#" + inputNames[0]).attr("checked", true)
    $('#name').hide()
  }


  function checkBoxSetting(name) {
    var indexOfItem = inputNames.indexOf(name)
    if (indexOfItem >= 0) {
      inputNames.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
    } else {
      inputNames.push(name);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('chked', JSON.stringify(inputNames));

    $('#name').toggle()
  }
});
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxName" onclick="checkBoxSetting(this.id)" />
```

You can not test it out here because stackoverflow will not let you save to local storage.

Comment: Yeah that hide the input, but when you refresh the page it still doesn't persist the input to be hidden. I tried this on plnkr

Comment: forgot to add, if you uncheck the box, it will hide the input and if you check it again it will show it. So its like a toggle function.

Comment: If you read my text it wont work on any jsfiddle, plnkr or other web compiler. And that is because they dont allow for local storage. But if you host you code och run it in any webbrowser as a .html file it will work.

Comment: they do use jsfiddle and plnkr do use localStorage

Comment: Yes, but they also clear the local storage when you reload the page. That is why you say it wont work.
Regarding you hide/show toggle, I have updated the code so it will hide and show the textbox depending on the checkbox

Comment: Hm strange its not working in my above code, added my `textarea` and `checkbox` html in my original post. and Added the `$("#" + inputNames[0]).attr("checked", true)` in the `if()` as well but somehow its still not persisting the textarea/checkbox.

Comment: but have you also change the HTML on the input of checkbox to <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxName" onclick="checkBoxSetting(this.id)" />

Comment: Yeah if you look at my `for()` line `chkBoxElement.click(function () {
          checkBoxSetting(this.id);
    });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132207/discussion-between-zorken17-and-mrnew).

Answer (score -2):

For Local Storage you should use Locker.

You will have to include one js library in your HTML file and then you will be able to store your data in local storage and even you will be able to get that even after refreshing the page.

Here is an example how you will be able to set value in local storage :

Lockr.set("status", "checked");

and you can get values back as follows :

var users = Lockr.get('status');

Here you can get locker.js library file :

https://github.com/tsironis/lockr/blob/master/lockr.js

Comment: why would you use another plugin to save it to localStorage when there's already a native one?

Comment: abstraction of fallback in case missing native support perhaps..?

Comment: @danwellman yeah probably, but I think I'll stick with native localStorage. Mind checking the plnkr I put above regarding the my question

Comment: Native is the way to go with modern browsers :)